# Is there a way that v-on:click displays modal for particular objects only?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

When I use the code below, it displays three buttons for SAN, DAVID, and JAY. If I click on SAN or David or Jay it generates the modal three times. Is there a way that when I click on button SAN, it displays modal only one time with the customerName (SAN) inside the modal?

My template file

```
<div id="app">
<div v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.createdAt">
  <div>
    <b-col md="3">
      <div v-for="item in post.items" v-bind:key="item.id">
      <div v-on:click="item.id = !item.id" style="color: blue;">
         <b-button v-b-modal.modal-xl variant="info">{{post.customerName}}</b-button>

            /** the code display the modal from BOOTSTRAP VUE **/

             <b-modal id="modal-xl" centered size="xl" title="TEAM NAME 1">
                <p> Booker Name = <u style="font-weight:bold;">{{post.customerName}}</u> </p>
                  <b-container class="bv-example-row">
                     <b-row style="font-weight:bold;">
                     <b-col><p>Child Name</p></b-col>
                     <b-col><p>Text Number</p></b-col>
                     <b-col><p>No Show</p></b-col>
                    </b-row>
                    <b-row>
                      <b-col><p>David</p></b-col>
                      <b-col><p>P</p></b-col>
                      <b-col><p>817 360 2705</p></b-col>
                      <b-col><input type="checkbox" v-model="subchildNoShow"/></b-col>
                    </b-row>
                </b-container>
             </b-modal>

             /** END OF MODAL **/

          </div>
       </div>
     </b-col>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Script Function

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {

  },

  data(){
    return{
      searchQuery: '',
      posts: [],
      subchildNoShow: []
    }
  }
}
```

JSON File values

```
data{
 Object[0]{
    customerName:'San',
    createdAt: '2020-04-15',
    items:{
       id:'1',
       arrivalTime:'06:00 PM'
    }
  }

  Object[1]{
    customerName:'David',
    createdAt: '2020-04-15',
    items:{
       id:'2',
       arrivalTime:'07:00 PM'
    }
  }

 Object[2]{
    customerName:'Jay',
    createdAt: '2020-04-15',
    items:{
       id:'3',
       arrivalTime:'07:00 PM'
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only create on modal. Move it outside of the `v-for`

```
            /** the code display the modal from BOOTSTRAP VUE **/

             <b-modal id="modal-xl" centered size="xl" title="TEAM NAME 1">
                <p> Booker Name = <u style="font-weight:bold;">{{selectedCustomerName}}</u> </p>
                  <b-container class="bv-example-row">
                     <b-row style="font-weight:bold;">
                     <b-col><p>Child Name</p></b-col>
                     <b-col><p>Text Number</p></b-col>
                     <b-col><p>No Show</p></b-col>
                    </b-row>
                    <b-row>
                      <b-col><p>David</p></b-col>
                      <b-col><p>P</p></b-col>
                      <b-col><p>817 360 2705</p></b-col>
                      <b-col><input type="checkbox" v-model="subchildNoShow"/></b-col>
                    </b-row>
                </b-container>
             </b-modal>

             /** END OF MODAL **/
```

and set `selectedPost` on `click` and show the modal.

```
<div v-on:click="selectItem(post, item)"
```

and declare the `selectItem` method

```
methods: {
 selectItem (post, item) {
  item.id = !item.id
  this.selectedCustomerName = post.customerName
  // show the modal
  $bvModal.show('modal-xl')
 }
}
```

Comment: when I used console.log(this.selectedCustomerName) it gives me the value which I clicked. Still its displaying three modal

Comment: Did you move the modal outside of both v-fors? You should create it before v-for="post in posts"

Comment: i just copied the modal code before v-for="post in posts" it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the modal component unique for each item as follows :

```
  <b-button @click="$bvModal.show('modal'+item.id)" variant="info">{{post.customerName}}</b-button>
               <!--    v----------------------^ -->
 <b-modal :id="'modal'+item.id" centered size="xl" title="TEAM NAME 1">
```

based on the [`modal instance show method`](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal#using-thisbvmodalshow-and-thisbvmodalhide-instance-methods) you concatenate the item id to the `modal` word which gives you for example `modal1` that is the method parameter, then provide this as an `id` to the modal via `:id="'modal'+item.id"`